# Redirection operators are not working in unix?

Tags: unix, io-redirection

I am running a program and it is printing all the printf statements on console.
But when I try to redirect them to any file using '>',the file gets created but there in no output of the program in the file.
Please help
When I run the below code in console:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

double time_diff(struct timeval x , struct timeval y);

struct timeval initial;
long sno=0;

void *process1 (void *sleepTimeForP1);
void *process2 (void *sleepTimeForP2);

pthread_mutex_t lock;

int main()
{
    gettimeofday(&initial , NULL);
    pthread_t trd1,trd2;
    int thread1,thread2;
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int *sleepTimeForP1;
    int *sleepTimeForP2;
    var1=rand()%9+1;
    sleepTimeForP1=&var1;
    var2=rand()%9+1;
    sleepTimeForP2=&var2;
    printf("S No.\tThread Number\tItem\tTime(usec)\n");
    thread1=pthread_create(&trd1,NULL,process1,(void *)sleepTimeForP1);
    thread2=pthread_create(&trd2,NULL,process2,(void *)sleepTimeForP2);
    pthread_join(trd1, NULL);
    pthread_join(trd2, NULL);
    printf("pthread1 = %d\n",thread1);
    printf("pthread2 = %d\n",thread2);

    return 0;
}

double time_diff(struct timeval x , struct timeval y)
{
    double x_ms , y_ms , diff;
    x_ms = (double)x.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)x.tv_usec;
    y_ms = (double)y.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)y.tv_usec;
    diff = (double)y_ms - (double)x_ms;
    return diff;
}

void *process1 (void *sleepTimeForP1)
{
    int *tsleepTimeForP1 = (int *)sleepTimeForP1;
    struct timeval end;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        sno++;
        gettimeofday(&end , NULL);
        printf("%ld\t1\t\t1.1\t%.0lf\n",sno,time_diff(initial, end));
        sno++;
        gettimeofday(&end , NULL);
        printf("%ld\t1\t\t1.2\t%.0lf\n",sno,time_diff(initial, end));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        sleep(1);
    }

}

void *process2 (void *sleepTimeForP2)
{
    int *tsleepTimeForP2 = (int *)sleepTimeForP2;
    struct timeval end;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        sno++;
        gettimeofday(&end , NULL);
        printf("%ld\t2\t\t2.1\t%.0lf\n",sno,time_diff(initial, end));
        sno++;
        gettimeofday(&end , NULL);
        printf("%ld\t2\t\t2.2\t%.0lf\n",sno,time_diff(initial, end));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

It give me the below output:

```
S No.   Thread Number   Item    Time(usec)
1   1       1.1 320
2   1       1.2 438
3   2       2.1 506
4   2       2.2 586
5   1       1.1 1000592
6   1       1.2 1000629
7   2       2.1 1000714
8   2       2.2 1000740
9   1       1.1 2000820
10  1       1.2 2000927
11  2       2.1 2000998
12  2       2.2 2001099
13  1       1.1 3001165
14  1       1.2 3001285
15  2       2.1 3001355
16  2       2.2 3001441
17  1       1.1 4001518
18  1       1.2 4001635
19  2       2.1 4001706
20  2       2.2 4001798
21  1       1.1 5001776
```

But when I do ./a.out > b.txt
I don't get any output on the console as well as in the file

Comment: Posting a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would make this question a lot easier to answer.

Comment: show us what you're trying to do? are you printing to stdout?

Comment: Buffering.  Are you waiting for the program to finish before looking in the file, or are you trying to look while it is still running but has not yet actually written any data?

Comment: Maybe the program prints to stderr, and you need to redirect filedescriptor 2 to 1 with `program 2>&1 >logfile`

Comment: done 'program 2>&1 >logfile' does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it is detected that the output is not directed to a terminal, the buffering is set to **block buffering** behind the scenes.
If you have waited long enough (probably for 4096 bytes of output to be generated), then the whole output would appear in bulk.

To solve this, you can either use `fflush(stdout);` after every `printf();` or force the buffering mode explicitly to **line buffering** at the beginning with `setlinebuf(stdout);`.

Check out the manpage of [setlinebuf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlinebuf) for further info.

Comment: Yes.When I wait long enough till the buffer gets full the file gets filled.

Answer (score 0):

I will be giving some pointers. Read  the [Linux Programming Book](https://www.nostarch.com/tlpi), to understand what is really happening.

I have added an `fflush(stdout)` after the relevant `printf()` statements of your code, i.e. `line 32,65,85`.

Once this is done, you will get the desired output. Now try to understand that why this kind of behavior occurs and why an explicit `fflush()` is required? I believe there should be some effort from the Question poster to understand the problem and to post a  [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Full Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

double time_diff(struct timeval x , struct timeval y);

struct timeval initial;
long sno=0;

void *process1 (void *sleepTimeForP1);
void *process2 (void *sleepTimeForP2);

pthread_mutex_t lock;

int main()
{
    gettimeofday(&initial , NULL);
    pthread_t trd1,trd2;
    int thread1,thread2;
    int var1;
    int var2;
    int *sleepTimeForP1;
    int *sleepTimeForP2;
    var1=rand()%9+1;
    sleepTimeForP1=&var1;
    var2=rand()%9+1;
    sleepTimeForP2=&var2;
    printf("S No...\tThread Number\tItem\tTime(usec)\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    thread1=pthread_create(&trd1,NULL,process1,(void *)sleepTimeForP1);
    thread2=pthread_create(&trd2,NULL,process2,(void *)sleepTimeForP2);
    pthread_join(trd1, NULL);
    pthread_join(trd2, NULL);
    printf("pthread1 = %d\n",thread1);
    printf("pthread2 = %d\n",thread2);

    return 0;
}

double time_diff(struct timeval x , struct timeval y)
{
    double x_ms , y_ms , diff;
    x_ms = (double)x.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)x.tv_usec;
    y_ms = (double)y.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)y.tv_usec;
    diff = (double)y_ms - (double)x_ms;
    return diff;
}

void *process1 (void *sleepTimeForP1)
{
    int *tsleepTimeForP1 = (int *)sleepTimeForP1;
    struct timeval end;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        sno++;
        gettimeofday(&end , NULL);
        printf("%ld\t1\t\t1.1\t%.0lf\n",sno,time_diff(initial, end));
        sno++;
        gettimeofday(&end , NULL);
        printf("%ld\t1\t\t1.2\t%.0lf\n",sno,time_diff(initial, end));
        fflush(stdout);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        sleep(1);
    }

}

void *process2 (void *sleepTimeForP2)
{
    int *tsleepTimeForP2 = (int *)sleepTimeForP2;
    struct timeval end;
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        sno++;
        gettimeofday(&end , NULL);
        printf("%ld\t2\t\t2.1\t%.0lf\n",sno,time_diff(initial, end));
        sno++;
        gettimeofday(&end , NULL);
        printf("%ld\t2\t\t2.2\t%.0lf\n",sno,time_diff(initial, end));
           fflush(stdout); 
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```